# Google maps shows up grey in hidden div

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have read the many threads on stack about this issue, but nothing will resolve my problem. I have the google map on a tab that is initially hidden when the page loads and would like some assistance please. Here is the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function loadsinglemap(){
  var mymap = new MeOnTheMap({
  container: "map_sidebar2",
  html: "<?php echo str_replace('"',"",$post->post_title); ?>",
  address: "<?php echo str_replace('"','',get_post_meta($post->ID, "map_location", true)); ?>",
  zoomLevel: 15,

  });                        
  } 

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {   loadsinglemap();  })

 </script>

This is on the page where the map is displayed:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.contact').click(function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(mymap, 'resize');
});
});
</script>
```

I just cannot get it to work. If anyone sees something that would help please respond.
Thanks

**EDIT:** Changed the element selector to a class, and my link to a class instead of an ID and it now at least picks it up. I get an error in firebug that "mymap is not defined".

Comment: Please give us a link to your page. That would be help for everyone.

Comment: I'm sorry, the site is still in a development environment so it's not available to the public. It's definitely related to the resize property as I just removed the line "jQuery(document).ready(function() {   loadsinglemap();  })" and now it loads correctly onclick. However it doesn't load at all if you go straight to the tab. And also on subsequent clicks of the link the grey image comes back.

Comment: Its now gotten to the stage where the map shows if I click twice on the link, but if I come back to the tab after its been hidden then it start off in grey mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call the initilize() function once again after you unhide the div.
i did it and it worked.
     [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/wvbdnb8o/187/)

Comment: Worked, thanks so much. Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 1):

I found instead of hiding the div set it's height / width to 0px; and set its overflow to hidden.

Helped me hope it helps you :)

Comment: The div that is hidden is my tab container which I am using jquery to show/hide.

Answer (score -2):

Check Roosko's answer here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/aUrVnx-i7LI , it works for me!

Since the map loads before the modal gets a defined size, it renders 
size as zero.

```
<a href="#?w=500" rel="popup2" class="poplight" onClick="initialize()">
    <img src='images/location1.png' title='Location' alt='images/location2.png' />
</a>
```

I called the `initilize()` function when the pop up is clicked.

Comment: Please add the most important points from the link in here. Links can become stale and the answer won't be useful any more.