# google maps refreshing grey

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a Google Map to a jquery. Mobile site javascript and the Google Maps API.  The problem is that every time I load the map, **most of the map is greyed out**.  I've done some research and apparently, I must add the command:

```js
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

But I've been fiddling with this for the last few hours and I can't seem to make it work.  This is the code I'm using:

```js
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.310774,66.225586);
      
      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
    
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    
      // boundry
      var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(31.207164,61.347656);
      var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(37.617713,69.785156);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
    
      
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484651/google-maps-shows-up-grey-in-hidden-div?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve that problem you need to:

1. make sure the div where the map is displayed has a valid size, if it is hidden, it will have zero size and you will need to display the div before it will have a valid size.  If it is sized using percentages, make sure that all of its parent elements either have a percent size or a specific size (see [Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial on the subject for details](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)).
2. once it has a size initialize the map (if you haven't already)
3. if it was already initialized, trigger the resize event on it.
4. You may need to set the center of the map after triggering the resize event.

You haven't provided enough information to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what other information I can add.  I've hard coded the size into the div tag

<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width:300px"></div> 

And I call the function as right at the start of the HTML.  I would be happy to provide more information.

Comment: The css.  The html.  The rest of the page.  Is the code running in an onload function?  If not that is the problem (the div doesn't have a size until the page finishes rendering and fires the onload event).

Comment: the code is running from a <body onLoad="initialize()"> function.  I have no other CSS on the DIV of the map, except the inline CSS listed here.  The rest of the HTML is at this point just a basic jquery.mobile page (since I was having trouble, I made an external page with nothing else on it except the map).  I suppose I could put the site online if you want to see the source code.

Comment: Putting it online (a link or a jsfiddle) would be helpful.  These problems are tricky to figure out without all the pieces.

Comment: Okay, the mobile app begins at http://www.streamwright.com and the relevant external file is at http://www.streamwright.com/map.html

Comment: So it is hidden to start.  Where is the code that causes it to be displayed?  You need to call either initialize or `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` there (and probably make "map" a global variable if you use the resize technique).

Comment: Can you add the code that needed to be changed to your question? Or update my answer to include it?  This is a common enough problem that a complete solution will be useful to someone in the future.

Comment: I didn't really change any of the code.  As soon as you said that it was hidden to start, I took everything off of that external page that might hide it.  Now whenever I call that link, the file isn't ever re-sized or hidden and so now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the Google Map Widget working before you start coding. You just need the Key ID, the latitude and longitude and use the app designer. The suggested zoom setting of 8 which comes up by default is adequate.
Here are some details:
http://hodentekmobile.blogspot.com/2016/07/intel-xdk-controls-6-using-google-map.html