# Google Maps Gray

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would say I have a rather simple problem, which are driving me nuts. On my customers web page http://alminde-akupunktur.dk/ at the bottom of the landing page, I'm using a Google Maps as a background. After I updated Google Maps API, the map turned gray and I've hadn't had any luck in solving this issue, the controls and marker are still being shown.

Can someone point me in the right direction for where the issue is? It is my CSS that is interfering with how Google Maps is rendered?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CSS-issue, forced by the setting of `max-height:100%` for `img` in http://alminde-akupunktur.dk/wp-content/themes/Akupunkturklinikken/assets/css/style.css (this rule also affects the map-tiles)

Add this rule to your CSS:

```
.gm-style img{max-height:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

try moving

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>
```

in the head section and not at the bottom of the html page. (is a library request and better if it is done before of the code use)

Answer (score 0):

related question: [google maps refreshing grey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268667/google-maps-refreshing-grey)

from that question:

> make sure the div where the map is displayed has a valid size, if it is hidden, it will have zero size and you will need to display the div before it will have a valid size. If it is sized using percentages, make sure that all of its parent elements either have a percent size or a specific size (see [Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial on the subject for details](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)).

Your map doesn't have a size.  If I move your the relevant code to a fiddle and give the div with id="frontpage-maps-canvas" a size, it works for me.  If I add the parent div with id="frontpage-maps" without any CSS it becomes grey.  If I give that div a size:

```
#frontpage-maps {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the map appears.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/daob7og6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function mapLoad() {
  console.log("map load...");

  // Google maps on front page
  function mapOption(zoom, type, draggable, scrollwheel) {
    return map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.5661181, 9.4885967),
      zoom: zoom,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      navigationControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      overviewMapControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      scrollwheel: scrollwheel,
      draggable: draggable,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: [{
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -100
        }, {
          "lightness": 65
        }, {
          "visibility": "on"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -100
        }, {
          "lightness": 51
        }, {
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -100
        }, {
          "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -100
        }, {
          "lightness": 30
        }, {
          "visibility": "on"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -100
        }, {
          "lightness": 40
        }, {
          "visibility": "on"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -100
        }, {
          "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        }, {
          "lightness": -25
        }, {
          "saturation": -100
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "hue": "#ffff00"
        }, {
          "lightness": -25
        }, {
          "saturation": -97
        }]
      }]
    }
  }

  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('frontpage-maps-canvas');

  if (mapCanvas) {
    var map_obj = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOption(16, 16, true, true));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.56595843045612, 9.482338428497314)
    });

    marker.setMap(map_obj);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
      var center = map_obj.getCenter();
      google.maps.event.trigger(map_obj, "resize");
      map_obj.setCenter(center);
    });
  };
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", mapLoad);
```

```css
html,
body,
#frontpage-maps-canvas,
#frontpage-maps {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="frontpage-maps">
  <div id="frontpage-maps-canvas"></div>
</div>
```