# Google Maps suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an app with the google-maps-api. One week ago everything works fine, but today, without changing the code, it suddenly stopped working...

When I start the map, nothing happens, I only see my app background.

Index.html

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*myKey*">
</script>
  ...
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas" 
     style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; "></div>
```

index.js

```
function map(x, y) {
  var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);  
  drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // Failed to find location, show default map
  function drawMap(defaultLatLng) {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: defaultLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    console.log("DRAW MAP START");
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    console.log("DRAW MAP END");
  }
}
```

No error appears, I only get the two outputs.
I hope, you can help me.

Thank you!

Ps: I tried a new Api key, but it's still not working...

**EDIT:** Im soo dump... :D
I tried height: 200px; and behold, there was something wrong with my css -.-

Comment: No error in the javascript console?

Comment: No, there's no error :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Gray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565943/google-maps-gray/34566572#34566572)