# Google maps shows up Grey, but works when resizing the browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

Hej. Google maps turns up grey in the browser, but can see the markers and the google logo in the bottom right corner.
Have tried the resize function, but still won't work.I am using bootstraps col.

I can see it works here, but it doesn't.
Thanks for the help.

```js
function initialize() {
    
    var myOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng(56.63914, 9.79765);

    var mapProp = {
        center: myOrigin,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);


    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(56.157165, 10.207644);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

    var myCenter2 = new google.maps.LatLng(57.04661, 9.924479);

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter2,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });


    marker2.setMap(map);

    /*On marker click, it zooms to 19*/

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(19);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(19);
        map.setCenter(marker2.getposition());
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#googleMap {
    height:350px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div id="googleMap"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: My first idea: when you initialize Google Maps, then the size of the map increases, Google Maps will work for the initial size, not that well for the larger size.  Does something like this happen?  Is it relevant?

Comment: Well, it dosn't work on mobil or a larger screen. Only shows, when resizeing the browser.

Comment: Can you post the error logs? You can also check this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268667/google-maps-refreshing-grey?rq=1) . Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i will check the link out. The error logs under here.

Comment: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys util.js:211 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Comment: How do you fix this problem sir

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3) for JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#map {
height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map;
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
zoom: 8
});
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## NOTE:

> If you're using the API under the standard plan, you must use a *browser key* (a type of API key) set up in a project of your choice. See more about [API keys for the standard API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key).