# GMAPS API not working in localhost

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-api-2

im trying to execute the first example of the GMAPS API key https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=es-419

in a example website in localhost, but the map doesnt load. The API Key its correct and checked with my google projects.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>



</head>

<div id="content">


<div id="header"> 
    <div id="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">MiEmpresa</a></h1>
        <h2><a href="" id="metamorph">Programación web a medida</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" title="">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="presupuesto.html" title="">Presupuesto</a></li>
            <li><a href="galeria.html" title="">Galería</a></li>
            <li><a href="localizacion.html" title="">Dónde estamos</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html" title="">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


 <div id="main_top">
<div id="main">
    <div id="right">
      <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB0t7voaGTqvsbCQ12MUWEfAquxMkLNBXc&callback=initMap">
    </script>

    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: clues are probably in your browser console

Comment: Your map div doesn't have a size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

related question: [google maps refreshing grey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268667/google-maps-refreshing-grey)

from that question:

> make sure the div where the map is displayed has a valid size, if it is hidden, it will have zero size and you will need to display the div before it will have a valid size. If it is sized using percentages, make sure that all of its parent elements either have a percent size or a specific size (see [Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial on the subject for details](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)).

Your map doesn't have a size.  If I add the following css:

```
  #right { height: 100%; }
  #main {height: 500px; }
  #map { height: 100%; }
```

the map appears.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#right {
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  height: 500px;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">


  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1><a href="#">MiEmpresa</a></h1>
      <h2><a href="" id="metamorph">Programación web a medida</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" title="">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="presupuesto.html" title="">Presupuesto</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="galeria.html" title="">Galería</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="localizacion.html" title="">Dónde estamos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contacto.html" title="">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="main_top">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="right">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are connected to intenet and the localhost is not offline

Try adding a width to your #map

```
    #map {
        height: 100%;  
        width: 500px;
   }
```

if work then you should assign a  proper width ( eg:  width: 100%;) to the map id and to all the parent container